# How to send httpRequest to server with GZIP DATA

Tags: java, android

I have a json file that I am sending to the server as a POST but it has to be gzipped

I dont know how to do it

I found the potential solution here [GZip POST request with HTTPClient in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153484/gzip-post-request-with-httpclient-in-java)

but I dont know how to merge the methodology they used in the second part of the answer with my makeHttpRequest method (they are using a multipart entity and Im using a urlencoded entity)

EDIT: Here is how I get jsonAsBytes

```
public static byte[] stringToGZIPByteArray (String string) {
    Log.d("string to be gzipped", string);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzos = null;

    try {
        gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
        gzos.write(string.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (gzos != null) {
            try { 
                gzos.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {

                };
        }
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
} // End of stringToGZIPByteArray
```

This is where I use that method

```
jsonParser.sendGzippedJSONviaHTTP(context, API.JSON_ACCEPT,    UtilityClass.stringToGZIPByteArray(jsonObject.toString()), context.getResources());
```

and this is sendGzippedJSONviaHTTP

```
public JSONObject sendGzippedJSONviaHTTP(Context context, String url, byte[] gzippedJSON, Resources res) {

    if (httpClient == null) {
        try {
            httpClient = new HttpClientBuilder().setConnectionTimeout(10000) 
                    .setSocketTimeout(60000) //
                    .setHttpPort(80)//
                    .setHttpsPort(443)//
                    .setCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore())//
                    .pinCertificates(res, R.raw.keystore, null) //
                    .build();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // request method is POST
        // defaultHttpClient

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        httpPost.setEntity(AndroidHttpClient.getCompressedEntity(gzippedJSON, context.getContentResolver()));


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();
        reader.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jsonObject;

} // End of makeHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html). You can use it instead of appache's `DefaultHttpClient`. It has a static method `getCompressedEntity(byte[] data, ContentResolver resolver)`

So, you can write:

```
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
 post.setEntity( AndroidHttpClient.getCompressedEntity( jsonAsBytes, null ) );
 httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

UPDATE:

this is the code from `AndroidHttpClient`:

```
public static AbstractHttpEntity getCompressedEntity(byte data[], ContentResolver resolver)
        throws IOException {
    AbstractHttpEntity entity;
    if (data.length < getMinGzipSize(resolver)) {
        entity = new ByteArrayEntity(data);
    } else {
        ByteArrayOutputStream arr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream zipper = new GZIPOutputStream(arr);
        zipper.write(data);
        zipper.close();
        entity = new ByteArrayEntity(arr.toByteArray());
        entity.setContentEncoding("gzip");
    }
    return entity;
}
```

should give you some insights

Comment: thanks I will let you know what happened when I get the chance to give it a try

Comment: I dont know why but this doesnt work. The server guys told me the format of what Im sending isnt right.

Comment: get the gzip file from the server guys and try do ungzip it and JSON-parse it

Comment: well the server returns something like [43@908a7sf

Comment: is that all? if so, than this is a `toString()` representation of `byte[]`

Comment: referring to the code sample I gave, how do you get `jsonAsBytes`?

Comment: I have provided more information in my question. Thanks!

Comment: ok, I see. You are double-GZIPing your json :)
either use `post.setEntity( new ByteArrayEntity( gzippedJSON ) )` or `post.setEntity( AndroidHttpClient.getCompressedEntity( jsonString.getBytes("UTF-8"), null ) )`